# How to access the variable values from URL in smarty template?

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty, query-string

I'm using PHP and smarty for my website. I'm getting a URL in address bar and I want to use the values from URL into smaarty template. So is it possible to do that? If yes can you explain? For your understanding I'm giving you the URL as follows:

```
http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/enquiries/manage_contact_us.php?contact_id=56&contact_full_name=ZainabJuzerBhavnagarwala&contact_email_id=fatemabhav21@gmail.com&op=view&reply_to_enquiry_suc=1&from_date=11/09/2000&to_date=11/09/2013
```

Suppose from the above URL I want to access the values of variables `contact_full_name` and `contact_email_id` in my smarty template which is currently being displaed. Can you explain me how could I achieve this?

Actually I tried the following code but it didn't output anything.

```
<input type="text" name="contact_full_name" id="contact_full_name" value="{ if $data.contact_full_name!=''} {$data.contact_full_name|capitalize} {else} {$contact_full_name|capitalize} {/if}" class="">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: {$smarty.get.contact_full_name} http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl

Answer (score 4):

Look at [smarty reserved variables](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl) :

```
{$smarty.get.contact_email_id}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [smarty reserved variables](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl) :

```
{$smarty.get.contact_email_id}
```

Since Smarty will output the contents of the variable, if present and nothing if it isn't, then you should just:-

```
<input type="text" name="contact_full_name" id="contact_full_name" value="{$smarty.get.contact_full_name|capitalize}" class="" />
```

(anyone can copy and paste LOL)

and per previous answer:

adding `$smarty->debugging_ctrl='URL';` to your php script and `&SMARTY_DEBUG` to the URL will popup your assigned variables (but not get and post)